# How to create MSAL accesstoken with Signed in USer and ROle including AAD Scope?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I have .net core Application.

I am trying to login via MSAL method. Once login done I need to generate Accesstoken for Accessing the Azure API. I am able to generate Accesstoken. But the token doesn't contains User and Role details.

I have claims like this

var claim = user.Claims.ToList();

And I am generating the Accesstoken using `ConfidentialClientBuilder()` like below

```
var app = ConfidentialCLientBuilder.Creat(ClientID)
.WithClientSecret(xxxxx)
.WithAuthority(xxxxxx).build();
```

Then for generating token I am following the below

```
var result = await app.AccquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync();

token = result.AccessToken;
```

But this token don't have user Role details.

Comment: [access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) shouldn't contain the user role information, it should only contain the consented app role information. [ID token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#payload-claims) contains user role information.

Comment: then why you want to contain user role in the access token?

Comment: You are authenticating with only application credentials. There can only be user information if a user is involved in the authentication process somewhere. You need to use AcquireTokenInteractive etc. to acquire the token.

Comment: Yes I understand. In case of ADAL I am abel to send ID tokens. But in MSAL I didn't find the way to send ID token along with Access Token. Is there any way??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
As I already having value in Context-Accessor I just used for Token-acquisition for generating the Access token. The for No Login-hint available issue I have used the below code in start up 

app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions
            {
                ExceptionHandler = ctx =>
                {
                    var feature = ctx.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                    if (feature?.Error is MsalUiRequiredException
                        or { InnerException: MsalUiRequiredException }
                        or { InnerException.InnerException: MsalUiRequiredException })
                    {
                        ctx.Response.Cookies.Delete($"{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.CookiePrefix}{CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme}");
                        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.Request.GetEncodedPathAndQuery());
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the ID token, we can use code below mentioned in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/msal/dotnet/acquiring-tokens/web-apps-apis/authorization-codes) to obtain it, but just like you see, the id token is basically generated when user sign in, and we need the [authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response-2) to do it.

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("client_id")
        .WithClientSecret("client_secret").Build();
var result = await app.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
            new[] { "openid", "profile", "offline_access" },
            "{authorization_code}").ExecuteAsync();
var idtoken = result.IdToken;
```

Therefore, I prefer to use access token to call graph api to [get the user roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-approleassignments?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Or using expand query parameter : `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id?$expand=appRoleAssignments`

Comment: I have done the changes and It's working fine now for the first login. But when I close the application and refresh the browser it's showing no login hint was given to AccquireTokenSilent

Comment: the error message `no login hint was given to AccquireTokenSilent` means `AccquireTokenSilent` requires a user-sign-in before calling this method, I'm afraid this issue comes from that after you refresh the browser and visit the website again, your app doesn't ask you to sign in..

Comment: Yes correct. Is there any solution when we refresh the application and keep the user details once login

Comment: sorry for the late reply, can this document help you on your requirement? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-manage-stay-signed-in-prompt

Comment: thanks for your inputs. But the above idea didn't worked out for me . I have tried the below concept. I have tried the   app.UseExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandlerOptions) in start up with some logic. It's worked for me. Let me post my changes. Again, thanks for the inputs.